# Why I can't activate SSL on my Ubuntu Server (20.04) with ldap auth? (ldaps)

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ldap, authentication, openldap

I have to activate SSL for secure comunications with ldap, I count with Letsencrypt .pem files (chain, fullchain, cert & privkey).

I followed the steps of some pages but it didn't had any effect in the test command.

What I did is:

I created duplicates of the .pem files

I changed the owner of all files to openldap:openldap

I created a .ldif file to make the next changes (let's name it serv.ldif)

```
dn: cn=config
replace: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /routeToCloneCerts/domain.com/fullchain.pem
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /routeToCloneCerts/domain.com/cert.pem
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /routeToCloneCerts/domain.com/privkey.pem
```

(The replace is because I can straight forward change them)

Now I run it with

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f serv.ldif
```

I edited the file "/etc/default/slapd" to add ldaps:///

```
SLAPD_SERVICES="ldap:/// ldapi:/// ldaps:///"
```

Then

```
sudo systemctl restart slapd
```

Finally I can do the test command

```
ldapwhoami -x -H ldaps://domain.com
```

But it says

```
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Both ports needed for ldap are open in the UFW firewall and none archive in  /etc/ldap was edited by hand, just with the ldapmodify, the clones of certs are in /etc/ldap/sasl2.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I run the command netstat and the port 636 on tcp and is listening.

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 636
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:636             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1214/slapd
tcp6       0      0 :::636                  :::*                    LISTEN      1214/slapd
```

nmap

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
389/tcp  open  ldap
636/tcp  open  ldapssl
2049/tcp open  nfs
```

**EDIT 3: DONE IT**
This week I'll put here how I did it (sorry I got a bit busy).

Comment: welcome. what does the logs says?

Comment: @djdomi Which logs I have to consult?

Comment: Is the server listening on port tcp/636?

Comment: @GregAskew Yes it is, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: What about ldp.exe? Does that connect? And nmap?

Comment: Sadly I can't access to the ldp.exe tool, but I know that I can log in with insecure protocol with the test accounts. I'll add nmap results.

Comment: Logs of `ldapsearch -d 7 ...` would be useful – those usually show the raw OpenSSL error messages.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I got interesting results, later I'll make an edit